# Creating gnome-shell applets/widget?

Tags: c++, c, linux, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extensions

I'm looking to create a simple tool, which will integrate into gnome-shell. I want the tool to be integrated in the "top-right control bar":

[image]

I want to have an entry in the upper right panel and I need to customize the "Popup" (in the picture, the place where the seek-bar is). My questions are:

1. What are those called? Applets? Widgets?
2. What is this bar called? Dash? Dock?
3. How do I create one myself, **entirely** in C/C++?

I read the resources on ["GnomeShellExtensions"](https://live.gnome.org/GnomeShell/Extensions) (including some third-party articles) and I found this ["Migration to DBus"](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/275295/Migrating-Panel-Applets-to-Gnome-Shell-using-DBus)-guide, too. Looking at the later one, it seems you will need to create the dock-entry with JavaScript and you can do the rest with a native language, which seems odd to me.

So, I'm looking for a way to make this entirely in C/C++.

I think it should be possible since NetworkManager (on the right side of the Dock/Bar) does it, too without having a gnome-shell extension (at least I can't find any).

Comment: Are you using C or C++? What do you mean by C/C++?

Comment: The libraries should be C-libraries, so it doesn't really madder. But I'm familiar with C and C++, I just don't want to use the JS-bindings. Therefor, I wrote C/C++

Answer (score 2):

1. They are "Extensions", "Gnome Extensions".
2. That is "Panel"
3. You should use JavaScript to develop an extension for Gnome.

To write an extension with new features that is not exists in libraries, you can develop it by C/C++, but finally you should use JavaScript to present it.

There are a lot of libraries starts with "gir" (abbreviation of "GObject Introspection Repository" OR "GIRepository") that may be helpful for you.